# How to efficiently update np array depending on index and value?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, python-3.6

I have an image of the sun, I found center and radius and now I want to process pixels differently if they are inside or outside the disk. The ideal solution would be to imterpolate the parameters of the processing function, in order to smoothly transition from disk to background.

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
for index,value in np.ndenumerate(sun_img):
    if distance.euclidean(index,center) > radius:
        sun_img[index] = processing_function(index,value)
```

Like this it works but it takes forever to compute the image. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do that. How would you solve this?

Image shape is around (1000, 1000)
Processing_function is basically not doing anything right now: value += 1

The function should be something like a non-linear "step function" with 0.0 value till radius and 1.0 5px after. something like: _______/''''''''''''''''''''' multiplied by the value of the pixel. The slope should be on the value of the radius. I wanna do this in order to enhance the protuberances

Comment: I still have to write the function, for now it is doing value += 1 just to see what happens. And it takes one century. The images are around (1k*1k)

Comment: No, greyscale, dtype np.float64

Comment: What about `radius` and `center`, are those scalars?

Comment: As you would guess center is a tuple and radius is a int, both in pixel coord. Center represents the center and radius the radius of the sun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized way leveraging [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
m,n = sun_img.shape  
I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]      
sq_dist = (I - center[0])**2 + (J - center[1])**2
valid_mask = sq_dist > radius**2
```

Now, for a `processing_function` that just adds `1` to the valid places, defined by the `IF-conditional`, do -

```
sun_img[valid_mask] += 1
```

---

If you need to implement a custom operation with `processing_function` that needs those row, column indices, use `np.where` to get those indices and then iterate through the valid elements, like so -

```
r,c = np.where(valid_mask)
for index in zip(r,c):
    sun_img[index] = processing_function(index,sun_img[r,c])
```

If you have a lot of such valid places, then computing `r,c` might make things slow. In that case, directly use the `mask`, like so -

```
for index,value in np.ndenumerate(sun_img):
    if valid_mask[index]:
        sun_img[index] = processing_function(index,value)
```

Compared to the original code, the benefit is that we have the conditional values pre-computed before going into the loop. The best way again would be to vectorize `processing_function` itself so that it works on a bigger chunk of data, but that would depend on its implementation.

Comment: I'm having lunch right now so I cannot try it but why would you think this is more efficient? I mean np.where reduces the number of pixel for the for but the order of magnitude is the same and you are accessing the pixels the same way

Comment: @RobiNoob Because you are doing a compute heavy operation of `distance.euclidean(index,center) > radius:` in a loop, which the suggested method does in a vectorized manner. Again, if your  `processing_function` is much more compute heavy than that, of course, you might not see big benefits. That's why I asked at the start if you can share the implementation of `processing_function`.

Comment: ok I'm back, I'm gonna give this a try. The function should be something like a non-linear "step function" with 0.0 value till radius and 1.0 5px after. something like: _______/''''''''''''''''''''' multiplied by the value of the pixel.
The slope should be on the value of the radius. I wanna do this in order to enhance the protuberances

Comment: @RobiNoob Please edit the question with the implementation.

Comment: It is faster this way!!!! you are right, it was the euclidean distance. I thought it was a memory access problem. Thank you